# WebResponse output html without Quotes

Tags: c#, response, webrequest

Now i have create a web request and getting response from that request. My response type is html. But in this html double quotes are missed in attributes. For example

```
<form method = POST name=xxxxx> <Body>
        <table **width=600 align=middle**>
                    <tr><td **align=middle**>Your Test below.</td></tr>
                    <tr> 
    </table>
```

Here Response content type is text/html

Comment: My response html attributes are missing double quotes. <form method=Post name=xxxx> instead of <form method="Post" name="xxxx">

Comment: I have tried to set response.ContentType = "text/html";